# bellman ford and dijkstra sparse vs dense graphs

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, weighted-graphs, dijkstras-algorithm

I believe using big o notation that Bellman-Ford is to be expected to be faster on sparse graphs and dijkstra's should be expected to be faster on dense graphs, but in practice dijkstra's is always faster and Bellman-Ford is only used when negative weight cycles are present. Is that the case?

Comment: I'd expect implementations designated Dijkstra's to differ more significantly than with Bellman-Ford. Both of us may be wrong.

Comment: (Please capitalise names, esp. of persons.)

Comment: Asked&answered at SO: [Bellman-Ford vs. Dijkstra graph density](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71641451/3789665)

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without wasting anybody's time. If you don't get a satisfying answer after a week or so, you may flag to request migration.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asked and answered on another site, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71641451/bellman-ford-vs-dijkstra-graph-density.